# How to parse a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

The string is `myAgent(9953593875).Amt:Rs.594` and want to extract `9953593875` from it. Here is what I tried:

```
NSRange range  =  [feDetails rangeOfString:@"."];
NSString *truncatedFeDetails = [feDetails substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)];
NSLog(@"truncatedString-->%@",truncatedFeDetails);
```

This outputs: `truncatedString-->AmzAgent(9953593875)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you do like this:

```
NSString *string = @"myAgent(9953593875).Amt:Rs.594.";

NSRange rangeOne = [string rangeOfString:@"("];
NSRange rangeTwo = [string rangeOfString:@")"];

if (rangeOne.location != NSNotFound && rangeTwo.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *truncatedFeDetails = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeOne.location + 1, rangeTwo.location - rangeOne.location - 1)];
    NSLog(@"%@",truncatedFeDetails);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

do like

**Step-1**

// split the string first based on `.`

for example

```
NSString *value = @"myAgent(9953593875).Amt:Rs.594.How I get 9953593875 only";

NSArray *arr = [value componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

NSString * AmzAgent = [arr firstObject];  // or use  [arr firstObject];

NSLog(@"with name ==%@",AmzAgent);
```

in here u get the output of `myAgent(9953593875)`

**Step-2**

in here use replace string like

```
AmzAgent = [AmzAgent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"myAgent("
                                               withString:@""];
AmzAgent = [AmzAgent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")"
                                               withString:@""];

 NSLog(@"final ==%@",AmzAgent);
```

finally you get output as `9953593875`

[image]

Comment: @"myAgent" is dynamic.It can changed .

Comment: @akshay -- oh ok ok then take the lovo answer , it will helps you, I dont want to override the code bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *str = @"myAgent(9953593875).Amt:Rs.594.";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\))"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:nil];
NSString *result = [str substringWithRange:[regex firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])].range];
//result = 9953593875
```